# In a JS class an AJAX success callback keeps returning Uncaught TypeError but the method is defined and I have no idea what's up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am making a successful AJAX call which returns data but I keep getting `sortable.class.js:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: buildTabs is not defined` in the success handling and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Does anyone see what's wrong with this?

**Instantiated and called with**

```js
const sortable = new Sortable();

sortable.v2Test();
```

**The Class**(shortened)

```js
class Sortable {
    constructor() {}

    v2Test() {
        this.v2Tabs();
    }

    buildTabs(dataset) {
        console.log('working');
    }

    v2Tabs() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/v2/tabs',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                buildTabs(data);
            },
        });
    }
}
```

===== Working version with passed function ====

```js
    this.v2Icons(1, 'tab1', this.processIcons); //call

    v2Icons(tab, targetElement, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/v2/icons/' + tab,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                callback(targetElement, data.icons, data.maxrow);
            },
        });
    }

    processIcons(targetElement, dataset, maxrow) {
        // do the shizzle
    });
```

Comment: The function is in the class, you've to call it using a correct refrence to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`success` function doesn't have reference to the parent object methods without a reference, to fix this you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which bind to the parent by default:

```
class Sortable {
    constructor() {}

    v2Test() {
        this.v2Tabs();
    }

    buildTabs(dataset) {
        console.log('working');
    }

    v2Tabs() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/v2/tabs',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: (data) => {
                this.buildTabs(data);
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I even though of that and tried to implement a callback solution where I would pass the function in the call which works in another AJAX success but I must have  made a mistake the few times I tried. I'll add the working call to my question as an edit.

Comment: Glad that you go it working. add it as answer you can accept it later!